# Regex query failing with spring + mongodb when used with java Pattern

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to query mongodb using it's regex functionality. I am using Spring boot with mongo repository. The implemented code is as below -

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(field).regex(Pattern.compile(value, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE));
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
mongoTemplate.find(query, DummyClass.class, collectionName);
```

But this fails with an exception -

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.util.regex.Pattern!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:435)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:391)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.convertToMongoType(MappingMongoConverter.java:1194)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.delegateConvertToMongoType(QueryMapper.java:441)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.convertId(QueryMapper.java:560)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedValue(QueryMapper.java:349)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObjectForField(QueryMapper.java:231)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.QueryMapper.getMappedObject(QueryMapper.java:140)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2235)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2225)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:770)
```

I want to understand the reason behind this problem, and if possible, a solution so as to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed. While providing configuration to MongoDB, I wanted to provide it custom conversion list where in I wanted to use custom converters for specific classes. I was providing it `CustomConversions`. Keeping the return type as `CustomConversions`, I actually returned the subclass `MongoCustomConversios`, like below -

```
@Bean
@Override
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
    converterList.add(new Converter1());
    converterList.add(new Converter2());
    converterList.add(new Converter3());

    return new MongoCustomConversions(converterList);
}
```

This resolved the issue that I was having.